# How can I select a checkbox in a sibling div using JQuery selectors?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Using JQuery selectors, how can I select the checkbox contained in the sibling div and remove the disabled property? (in the example code below, I need the checkbox in the div with the class of `col-3`)  I can't just put a class on the checkbox and use that because I have multiple occurrences where I have this same structure, so I need to do it dynamically based on the HTML layout.  I have tried a combination of selectors including `next()`, `closest()` and `siblings()` but I can't seem to target the checkbox successfully.

My HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class = "col-6">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </label>
</div>

<div class = "col-3">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the containing div, use `$(this).closest("div")`. To get its siblings, call `.siblings()`. Then use `.find()` to find the checkboxes that they contain.

```js
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("div").siblings().find(":checkbox").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-6">
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </label>
</div>

<div class="col-3">
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
  </label>
</div>
```